# Converting SQL table to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have been struggling with converting a SQL table elements into a 3 tiered XML table.  I have it almost there but I know I am just missing one small piece somewhere.

Here is what I am looking for:

```
<labels _FORMAT="\US Labels\ChemSamples.lwl" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNUMBER="10">
  <label>
    <variable name="HBANumber">1234</variable>
    <variable name="BatchNumber">567</variable>
    <variable name="BagNumber">1</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeTop">123601</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeText">123601</variable>
    <variable name="HBANumberSmall">1234</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedSmall">123601</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeBottom">123601</variable>
    <variable name="CreatedDate">02/10/2015</variable>
    <variable name="Operator">7197</variable>
    <variable name="PrintDate">02/10/2015</variable>
  </label>
</labels>
```

I have create a temp table to generate the data and my SQL query looks like this:

```
declare @tmpTable table(fieldname varchar(25), fieldvalue varchar(20))

insert into @tmpTable values('HBANumber','1234')
insert into @tmpTable values('BatchNumber','567')
insert into @tmpTable values('BagNumber','1')
insert into @tmpTable values('CombinedBarcodeTop','123601')
insert into @tmpTable values('CombinedBarcodeText','123601')
insert into @tmpTable values('HBANumberSmall','1234')
insert into @tmpTable values('CombinedSmall','123601')
insert into @tmpTable values('CombinedBarcodeBottom','123601')
insert into @tmpTable values('CreatedDate','02/10/2015')
insert into @tmpTable values('Operator','7197')
insert into @tmpTable values('PrintDate','02/10/2015')
SELECT
    '\US Labels\ChemSamples.lwl' AS '@_FORMAT',
    1 AS '@_QUANTITY',
    10 AS '@_PRINTERNUMBER',
    (select null,
        (select fieldname AS '@name', fieldvalue as 'variable'
            from @tmpTable
            for XML path ('variable'), type)
    for XML PATH ('label'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('labels')
```

Executing this query returns the following results:

```
<labels _FORMAT="\US Labels\ChemSamples.lwl" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNUMBER="10">
  <label>
    <variable name="HBANumber">
      <variable>1234</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="BatchNumber">
      <variable>567</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="BagNumber">
      <variable>1</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeTop">
      <variable>123601</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeText">
      <variable>123601</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="HBANumberSmall">
      <variable>1234</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CombinedSmall">
      <variable>123601</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeBottom">
      <variable>123601</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CreatedDate">
      <variable>02/10/2015</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="Operator">
      <variable>7197</variable>
    </variable>
    <variable name="PrintDate">
      <variable>02/10/2015</variable>
    </variable>
  </label>
</labels>
```

Does anyone have an idea on what I can do to get it to look like the first item I listed?

Thanks

Comment: I don't actually have SQLServer handy to try this, but what would happen if you changed that innermost select to "select fieldname AS '@name', fieldvalue from @tmpTable for XML path ('variable'), type" ?

Comment: I know you can easily make that a part of the previous variable if you wanted it as like a value attribute (fieldvalue as '@value'), however in my experience, the only way to combine attributes and tag values is with custom creating the XML.  This link is a resource I commonly use: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/

Comment: @unigeek, I tried that method before and then I ended up with the element of <fieldvalue>value</fieldvalue>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
SELECT 
    '\US Labels\ChemSamples.lwl' AS '@_FORMAT',
    1 AS '@_QUANTITY',
    10 AS '@_PRINTERNUMBER',
    (select null,
        (SELECT 1 AS Tag, 
                NULL AS Parent, 
                fieldname AS [variable!1!name], 
                fieldvalue AS [variable!1!!ELEMENT]
          FROM @tmpTable
        FOR XML EXPLICIT, TYPE)
     FOR XML PATH ('label'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('labels')
```

The key is to use the FOR XML EXPLICIT clause, to allow you to format the XML with more control, and the secret to mixing both attributes and the value into the same node is to omit the node name in the second clause (the two "!!" next to each other).

What this returns for me when I run it:

```
<labels _FORMAT="\US Labels\ChemSamples.lwl" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNUMBER="10">
  <label>
    <variable name="HBANumber">1234</variable>
    <variable name="BatchNumber">567</variable>
    <variable name="BagNumber">1</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeTop">123601</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeText">123601</variable>
    <variable name="HBANumberSmall">1234</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedSmall">123601</variable>
    <variable name="CombinedBarcodeBottom">123601</variable>
    <variable name="CreatedDate">02/10/2015</variable>
    <variable name="Operator">7197</variable>
    <variable name="PrintDate">02/10/2015</variable>
  </label>
</labels>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That came close, the elements actually looked like : <variable name="Operator" ELEMENT="7197" />, so I will have to see if our software can handle that structure.

Comment: It didn't look that way when I ran it... hrm... what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I re-tested the SQL and re-pasted it, in case I had a typo in what got put into the message here (I did edit it after the fact and may have mucked something up).  I also copied and pasted the results I see. Can you try again?

Comment: That worked perfectly!!  I think I left out the double !! on Element. Thanks.  And we are using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

@pmbAustin, there is actually no need for XML EXPLICIT, this will get the requested result. To get your result, replace `, [variable]    = fieldvalue` with `, [text()]    = fieldvalue`.

```
SELECT 
      [@_FORMAT]          = '\US Labels\ChemSamples.lwl'
    , [@_QUANTITY]        = 1
    , [@_PRINTERNUMBER]   = 10
    , [label]             = (   SELECT 
                                      [@name]       = fieldname 
                                    , [variable]    = fieldvalue
                                FROM @tmpTable
                                FOR XML PATH ('variable'), TYPE
                            )
FOR XML PATH ('labels')
```

Comment: Thanks for that info... you're right, after replacing [variable] with [text()] you do get the desired results.